# Good morning maneuver to fail a squat?

Tags: squats, exercise-technique

This is mentioned in [this video](https://youtu.be/aav3R81SxOg?t=514) by Mark Rippetoe. I can't understand how is that maneuver possible.

How does one go into the hip hinge position related to the good morning when they're at the bottom of a deep squat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He means "good morning" in that all you do is fall forward. You can even see in the video that the woman doesn't actually "Good morning" the bar. She just sinks as low as she can in the hole then disengages her torso so her chest falls forward and the bar catches the pins. Doing it this way keeps your feet firmly planted on the floor and your lower back relatively stable.

Ideally, the pins should only be a few inches or centimeters below your lowest point when your chest is properly upright. Keeping proper form should ensure you never smack the pins. If you lower your chest, then the bar should catch the pins.

This is an easier approach to failing a squat than "dumping the bar" which requires you to cave your knees forward so you can throw the bar behind you. You do this move if you don't have safety pins or spotters, but it takes practice and is more dangerous.